# Postmapping annotation not working in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, rest

GetMapping works but postmapping is not working. When I am trying to access post method I get 404 . I tried to write some logs in it with sysout or log but the method not working . All details below thank you in advance.

My Controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
@Slf4j
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/gettest")
    public String getTest(){
    return "gettest w orking";
    }

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public String testMet(@RequestBody String name) {
        System.out.println("wttttf");
        return "turnsomething";
    }
```

i tried with consumes and produces properties but not working with them . Getmapping works but postmapping not  . And also i tried with jacksondatabind like below import so with that i dont need consumes produces properties but post mapping not working .

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Idk it's related to that or not my security config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().and().cors().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().anyRequest()
        .permitAll()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error").and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
            .clearAuthentication(true).invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSSESIONID","remember-me")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().formLogin();
    }
```

Comment: try removing @RequestMapping("/")
I believe the path will be //test otherwise

Comment: It's working now thank you but i dont understand something that how get mapping works even if has // on it ? Can you have any point about that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try by first disabling csrf in your spring security configuration class by implementing 'configure(HttpSecurity http)' method to see if it still gives an error.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
  }
}
```